# MySql get sum of a subquery, the subquery has a union

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table, union

I'm new to mysql but not new to sql.  Below is my code and error message

> Error: 42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'select content_type, count(*) as Red, 0 as Green
>   from touchpoints ' at line 3

```
SELECT content_type, SUM(Red), SUM(Green)
FROM (
         select content_type, count(*) as Red, 0 as Green
         from touchpoints
         where evaluatee_user_id = 6
           and color_code = 'R'
         group by content_type
         UNION
         select content_type, 0 as Red, count(*) as Green
         from touchpoints
         where evaluatee_user_id = 6
           and color_code = 'G'
         group by content_type
    )
GROUP BY content_type
```

The subquery works and the output is:

```
M   1   0
SCI 5   0
SFA 3   0
SS  1   0
M   0   3
```

Comment: You need a table alias after the `)`.   I consider this a typo and vote to close.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct about the alias, thank you.

Comment: For Pivoting in MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this query by using conditional aggregation:

```
 select content_type, sum(color_code = 'R') as Red, sum(color_code = 'G') as Green
 from touchpoints
 where evaluatee_user_id = 6
 group by content_type;
```

No subquery is needed at all.

Comment: This was a perfect alternative to my mes